# Como aumentar select com css proporcionalmente

Tags: css

Tenho em uma página em select que mostra as lojas que tenho cadastrado em meu BD, consegui um css que alterou o layout do mesmo deixando-o mais agradável, mas estou com um problema, preciso que esse select fique maior e ao alterar o tamanho em height ele aumenta a altura mas fica desproporcional, página pode ser vista aqui:

[Select estilizado](http://moveissaobento.com.br/msb/promocoes)

O css que consegui foi esse:

```
.dropdown {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 30px;
  width: 150px;
  background: #f2f2f2;
  border: 1px solid;
  border-color: white #f7f7f7 #f5f5f5;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, transparent, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06));
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, transparent, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06));
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, transparent, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06));
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, transparent, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06));
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
  box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
}
.dropdown:before, .dropdown:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  top: 9px;
  right: 10px;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border: 4px dashed;
  border-color: #888 transparent;
  pointer-events: none;
}
.dropdown:before {
  border-bottom-style: solid;
  border-top: none;
}
.dropdown:after {
  margin-top: 7px;
  border-top-style: solid;
  border-bottom: none;
}

.dropdown-select {
  position: relative;
  width: 200%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 6px 8px 6px 10px;
  height: 28px;
  line-height: 14px;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #62717a;
  text-shadow: 0 1px white;
  /* Fallback for IE 8 */
  background: #f2f2f2;
  /* "transparent" doesn't work with Opera */
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) !important;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 0;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}
.dropdown-select:focus {
  z-index: 3;
  width: 100%;
  color: #394349;
  outline: 2px solid #49aff2;
  outline: 2px solid -webkit-focus-ring-color;
  outline-offset: -2px;
}
.dropdown-select > option {
  margin: 3px;
  padding: 6px 8px;
  text-shadow: none;
  background: #f2f2f2;
  border-radius: 3px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

/* Fix for IE 8 putting the arrows behind the select element. */
.lt-ie9 .dropdown {
  z-index: 1;
}
.lt-ie9 .dropdown-select {
  z-index: -1;
}
.lt-ie9 .dropdown-select:focus {
  z-index: 3;
}

/* Dirty fix for Firefox adding padding where it shouldn't. */
@-moz-document url-prefix() {
  .dropdown-select {
    padding-left: 6px;
  }
}
```

Comment: Aqui parece direito...

Comment: Seria isso? http://jsfiddle.net/tor4z799/1/

Comment: Olá @abfurlan, isso mesmo, mas o tamanho agora ficou um pouco exagerado, preciso um pouco menor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você precisa alterar os seguintes trechos do seu código conforme comentado no código abaixo:

```css
.dropdown {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 60px; /*ALTERE PARA O TAMANHO DESEJADO*/
  width: 150px;
  background: #f2f2f2;
  border: 1px solid;
  border-color: white #f7f7f7 #f5f5f5;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, transparent, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06));
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, transparent, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06));
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, transparent, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06));
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, transparent, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06));
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
  box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
}
.dropdown:before, .dropdown:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  top: 25px; /*ALTERE PARA O TAMANHO DESEJADO*/
  right: 10px;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border: 4px dashed;
  border-color: #888 transparent;
  pointer-events: none;
}
.dropdown:before {
  border-bottom-style: solid;
  border-top: none;
}
.dropdown:after {
  margin-top: 7px;
  border-top-style: solid;
  border-bottom: none;
}

.dropdown-select {
  position: relative;
  width: 200%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 6px 8px 6px 10px;
  height: 60px; /*ALTERE PARA O TAMANHO DESEJADO*/
  line-height: 20px; /*ALTERE PARA O TAMANHO DESEJADO*/
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #62717a;
  text-shadow: 0 1px white;
  /* Fallback for IE 8 */
  background: #f2f2f2;
  /* "transparent" doesn't work with Opera */
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) !important;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 0;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}
.dropdown-select:focus {
  z-index: 3;
  width: 100%;
  color: #394349;
  outline: 2px solid #49aff2;
  outline: 2px solid -webkit-focus-ring-color;
  outline-offset: -2px;
}
.dropdown-select > option {
  margin: 3px;
  padding: 6px 8px;
  text-shadow: none;
  background: #f2f2f2;
  border-radius: 3px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

/* Fix for IE 8 putting the arrows behind the select element. */
.lt-ie9 .dropdown {
  z-index: 1;
}
.lt-ie9 .dropdown-select {
  z-index: -1;
}
.lt-ie9 .dropdown-select:focus {
  z-index: 3;
}

/* Dirty fix for Firefox adding padding where it shouldn't. */
@-moz-document url-prefix() {
  .dropdown-select {
    padding-left: 6px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">          
<form action="promocao.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="form1" id="form1">
    <select name="id_loja" id="id_loja" onchange="this.form.submit();" class="dropdown-select">
            <option value="1">Mandaguari</option>
            <option value="2">Maringá</option>
            <option value="3">Apucarana</option>
          </select>
</form>
</div>
```

Comment: Olá @abfurlan, muito obrigado pela excelente dica, me ajudou muito.